# Disable escaping in JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

How to put text to `Element` object without escaping?

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
Elements els = doc.select("script");
for(Element element: els) {
    element.text("Text that should not be escaped. eq '&'");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import org.jsoup.nodes.DataNode;


element.empty();
element.appendChild(new DataNode("Text that should not be escaped. eq '&'"));
```