# How can I disable characters escape for jsoup@1.10.2+

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to disable escape mode in jsoup, and i found a way worked before jsoup@1.10.x:

```
Entities.EscapeMode.base.getMap().clear();
```

However, the method getMap() was totally removed at jsoup@1.10.2, and for some reason I can't downgrade the version of jsoup. Will anybody help me for this problem? Thanks.

Comment: How do you insert the elements you want to escape? If you use `element.text`, you can use `element.append(new DataNode())` instead as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47461755/10871900)

Comment: I insert elements by Document select, Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(myHTMLTemplate); Elements table = doc.select("tr");

Comment: And what is escaped? Everything inside the document? How do you insert the document, then?